# Detecting .scroll on div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**EDIT**: looks like I was approaching this from the wrong direction, will see if I can close this. Future reading:

[Get mouse wheel events in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery)

---

I'm trying to create a scrollable `<div>` element (on a horizontal plane); not there with the maths yet but I'm having trouble with something more basic - the scroll event doesn't seem to be registering. Am I missing anything obvious?

I've taken out all the CSS associated with the `<div`> barring what you see in the samples below:

```
<div id="about-carousel" carousel-offset="0" style="height:20rem; background-color:red;">

</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    handleCarousels(['#about-carousel']);
});

function handleCarousels(idArray) {
    for(var n in idArray) {
        var target = idArray[n];
        // this works
        $(target).click(function() {
            console.log('clicked');
        });

        // this doesn't
        $(target).scroll(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            console.log('scrolls');
        });
    }
}
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097246/jquery-detect-scroll-on-included-element) the element needs to have `overflow: scroll` set, but that makes no difference. Even if I fill the `<div>` with images, it doesn't trigger the `.scroll` event at all.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE BEFORE POSTING**: the 'scrolls' message is being output to console if I set the div to `overflow: scroll` and fill it with images, but *only* when I drag the scroll bar. I thought it was meant to capture mouse events too?

I'm using jQuery 1.11.1.

Comment: *"but only when I drag the scroll bar. I thought it was meant to capture mouse events too?"* - Nope, it's just supposed to capture a [scroll event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll). Which means only when you drag the scroll bar, or the scroll bar is moved.

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/o0sjzbxx/1/

Comment: Appreciate the replies, looks like I was looking at this from the wrong direction.